# Putting a "in list" into an if statement

Tags: python

I am currently in the process of creating a hangman game. My problem is in the 2nd for loop, for x in wordlist. This for loop is supposed go through the wordlist (in this example ['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O']) and:

`if x in newwordlist or x==guessedletter`, then x is printed onto the new list

`elif x not in newwordlist or x!=guessed letter`, then a "-" is printed for that value.

When I type the letter H in the console as the guessedletter.
The newwordlist updates and becomes ['H', '-', '-', '-', '-'] because I specified in the code that if x=guessedletter then print.

But, when I proceed with the next input, like O. The newwordlist is now ['-', '-', '-', '-', 'O'].
How do I make it so that it instead becomes ['H', '-', '-', '-', 'O'].

My for loop specifies that if x is in newwordlist then print it and if it is not, then do not print "-". Why is it not remembering that the newwordlist contains the value H and should not replace with a dash. It should instead print that value.

```
ALPHABET = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U',
            'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

word = input()  # word player 2 is trying to guess
wordlist = list(word)  # word in list form
guessedletter = input()  # guessed letter
guesses = 6  # max amount of guesses

while guesses <= 6 and guesses > 0:
    newABC = []
    newABCstring = ('')
    for x in ALPHABET:
        if x != guessedletter:
            newABC.append(x)
            newABCstring = (newABCstring + str(x))
    print("Unused letters:" + " " + (newABCstring))
    ALPHABET = newABC

    newwordlist = []

    for x in wordlist:  # ['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O']
        if x in newwordlist or x == guessedletter:
            newwordlist.append(x)
        elif x not in newwordlist or x != guessedletter:
             newwordlist.append('-')  # ['-', '-', 'L', 'L', '-']
    print(newwordlist)

    newwordliststring = ('')
    for x in newwordlist:
        newwordliststring = (newwordliststring + str(x))
        if len(newwordliststring) == len(newwordlist):
            print("Guess the word," + " " + (newwordliststring))  # prints the guessedletter+dashes in string form


    guessedletter = input()
```

Answer (score 0):

The "newwordlist = []" is executed for each iteration in the while loop. Thus even 'H' is set in the previous iteration, it is reset to [].

You can have a newwordlist with element initialized all to '-' outside the while loop. Every time the player guesses the letter correctly, simply update that list instead of appending elements to the list.

```
newwordlist = ['-' for x in wordlist]
while guesses > 0:
    # some code
    for idx, letter in enumerate(wordlist):
        if letter == wordlist[idx]:
            newwordlist[idx] = letter
    print(newwordlist)
    # remaining code
```

Comment: I see, is there a way for me to put "newwordlist = []" inside the for loop? While also setting it to the output of that for loop? That way I could loop with the new list with "H".

Comment: Well, technically yes if you save the state elsewhere. But you have to have something outside the loop in order to save states.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following.

1. place the newwordlist outside the while loop
2. just replace the index of the newwordlist inside the for loop.
   See code below.

`

```
ALPHABET = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U',
            'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

word = input()  # word player 2 is trying to guess
wordlist = list(word)  # word in list form
guessedletter = input()  # guessed letter
guesses = 6  # max amount of guesses

#define the newwordlist outside while loop
newwordlist = ['-' for letter in word]
while guesses <= 6 and guesses > 0:
    newABC = []
    newABCstring = ('')
    for x in ALPHABET:
        if x != guessedletter:
            newABC.append(x)
            newABCstring = (newABCstring + str(x))
    print("Unused letters:" + " " + (newABCstring))
    ALPHABET = newABC

#     newwordlist = []

    for index, x in enumerate(wordlist):  # ['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O']
        if x in newwordlist or x == guessedletter:
            #just replace the value in the newwordlist
            newwordlist[index] = x  
            #blow elif is not required
#         elif x not in newwordlist or x != guessedletter:
#              newwordlist.append('-')  # ['-', '-', 'L', 'L', '-']
    print(newwordlist)

    newwordliststring = ('')
    for x in newwordlist:
        newwordliststring = (newwordliststring + str(x))
        if len(newwordliststring) == len(newwordlist):
            print("Guess the word," + " " + (newwordliststring))  # prints the guessedletter+dashes in string form


    guessedletter = input()
```

`

Comment: This is a great answer that solves the problem, however I must follow the guidelines set for the program, and that includes not using the enumerate function.

Comment: enumerate just gives you index value for the for loop. without enumerate you will not get the index of the iterated value. Not sure what is the use case here.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this and compare it with yours:

```
class E(Exception): pass

A = []

for i in range(65, 91):
    A.append(chr(i))

w = []

for i in 'HELLO':
    w.append(i)

g = ['-'] * len(w)
d = {}

for i in w:
    d[i] = 0

print('Please guess the word :\n%s\n' % g)
while True:
    try:
        i = input('Guess letter/word: ').upper()
        if __debug__:
            if len(i) != 1 and i not in A:
                raise AssertionError('Only a single letter and ASCII permitted')
            else: raise E
    except AssertionError as e:
        print('\n%s' % e.args[0])
        continue

    except E:
        if i in w:
            if i not in g:
                g[w.index(i, d[i])] = i
                d[i] = w.index(i)
                print(g)
            else:
                try:
                    g[w.index(i, d[i]+1)] = i
                    d[i] = w.index(i, d[i]+1)
                    print(g)
                except ValueError:
                    continue

        if w == g:
            print('You are great')
            break
```

Output:

```
PS D:\Python> python p.py
Please guess the word :
['-', '-', '-', '-', '-']

Guess letter/word: h
['H', '-', '-', '-', '-']
Guess letter/word: e
['H', 'E', '-', '-', '-']
Guess letter/word: l
['H', 'E', 'L', '-', '-']
Guess letter/word: l
['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', '-']
Guess letter/word: l
Guess letter/word: l
Guess letter/word: o
['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O']
You are great
```